# Create divs and add images on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating 4 divs and adding 4 images in to each div.

```
var divid = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"], 
    imgid = ["a.png","b.png","c.png","d.png"];
for(var i = 0; i < divid.length;i++ ){
   document.write('<div id="'+divid[i]+'" class="divCl"><input type="image" src="'+imgid[i]+'" class="imgCl"/></div>');
}
```

css:-

```
.divCl{
   /*display: none;*/
}
.imgCl{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Why isn't the css applying? also is it ok to use this method to create divs and add images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `document.write` will overwrite the entire contents of the DOM once the document is loaded so you should not use this. You should instead use `document.getElementById` to select the parent element where you want to insert the images and then set the `.innerHTML` of that element to the new images. Here is an example:

HTML

```
<div id="imgParent"></div>
```

JS

```
var divid = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"], 
    imgid = ["a.png","b.png","c.png","d.png"];
var imgs = '';

for(var i = 0; i < divid.length;i++ ){
   imgs += '<div id="'+divid[i]+'" class="divCl"><input type="image" src="'+imgid[i]+'" class="imgCl"/></div>';
}

var parent = document.getElementById('imgParent');
parent.innerHTML = imgs;
```

Output HTML

```
<div id="imgParent">
    <div id="aa">
        <input type="image" src="a.png" class="imgCl" />
    </div>
    <div id="bb>
        <input type="image" src="b.png" class="imgCl" />
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: No, just once. The `document.getElementById` is to get the "container" that the other divs will be put inside of. The last line takes all of the other divs and imgs and puts them inside of the "container" div (`<div id="imgParent"></div>`).

Comment: Added some example output for clarification. Please remember to mark as the answer if this is the one you accept.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error. 
Your arrays elements are not strings. **The elements are variables not defined**. I used jQuery to append each div to the body.

```
var divid = ['aa','bb','cc','dd'], 
    imgid = ['a','b','c','d'];

for(var i = 0; i < divid.length; i++ ) {
   var str = $('<div id="'+ divid[i] +'" class="divCl"><input type="image" src="'+ imgid[i] +'" class="imgCl"/></div>');
   $('body').append(str);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hjepjnk3/

Answer (score 0):

Going the document.write route will cause your CSS (and everything else) to be overwritten.  A better way would be to create a container div and place the new div's in there

```
var divid = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"], 
imgid = ["a.png","b.png","c.png","d.png"];

for(var i = 0; i < divid.length;i++ ){
    document.getElementById('containerDiv').innerHTML += '<div id="'+divid[i]+'" class="divCl"><input type="image" src="'+imgid[i]+'" class="imgCl"/></div>'
}
```

You could also just add it directly to the body by doing

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML
```